# DNS Settings and Switching Name Servers: Will this work?

Tags: domain-name-system, linode

this is kind of a follow up of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/443914/single-domain-name-potentially-resolving-to-multiple-servers/), although this is more of a specific question regarding a solution I came up with, inspired by one of the responses.

- I currently have an old website on `Server A` that is a shared server with very limited settings.
- I have the new site on `Server B` running on a Linode.
- I want `www.somedomain.com` to point to the new site on Server B's IP Address (note: `www.`)
- I want `somedomain.com` to point to old site, `Server A`'s IP Address, which will 301 redirect most requests to `www.somedomain.com` (i.e. the new site).

I've created a DNS Zone in Linode and redefined all DNS settings, including `MX` records and other `A` records for ftp, mx, pop, smtp. I've used [network-tools.com](http://network-tools.com) and checked all `A` records and mx records. I can't see any `CNAME`s or anything else.

I'm still pretty new to all of this, but my theory is that if I now change the Name Servers being used to point to the Linode Name Servers, then the DNS Zone settings I've defined will take effect (after propagation time). Assuming all my DNS settings are the same as the old DNS settings (as seen on network-tools), except for the `www.` subdomain, everything should smoothly transition, right?

Will my theory work? If I change the Name Servers to Linodes 5 name servers, will the settings at Linode be used instead of the old name servers? Can anyone think of any other factors that might affect this logic?

*I understand this is a convoluted solution to what seems to be a trivial task, but I have a convoluted problem. If you wish to offer a new solution, please read the question I linked to above, I'll be very happy to hear all suggestions!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound convoluted to me.

The naked domain points to Server A. Requests will be redirected to Server B.

WWW points to Server B.

You're moving your name servers to Linode.

Done.

Just make sure that you update/change the name servers at your Registrar (which may also be your current DNS hoster or it may be your current web site hoster).

**CAVEAT**

Moving your web site doesn't technically require you to move your name servers. If it's a TOS (Terms of Service) with the old web site host or the new web site host then you may have to but it's important to understand that this is not technically required. For example:

Network Solutions is the Registrar for my domain

DynDNS hosts my DNS zones

GoDaddy hosts my web site

Google hosts my email

Or any combination of the above

Comment: Hi joeqwerty! Thanks for your reply. I need to switch my name servers because I have no control over my DNS settings (cannot create A records, MX records) at the current host - the only thing I can control, oddly enough, is WHAT name servers I use. This is why I wish to use Linode's Name Servers so I can use my own settings - especially since content on the old server will still be used in some cases. But from the sounds of your reply, I can just go to my current host, enter Linode's name servers, and assuming my setup is right, things should be fine. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.